# Make object move from A to B and back again all the time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I've created a little 2D game in Unity and I'm still very new to Unity.
I tried long and hard to search and check a guild / tutorial about how to make my "monster" move from A -> B and when he reach B then move back again. This he needs to keep doing all the time.

The Monster has a `Box Collider` and a `Rigidbody` and a `"Destroyer" script` so that if you run into him, you die.

I would really love to get a little help about how to create the monster movement.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Please be more specific, see http://tinyurl.com/stack-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple, basically what you're looking for is a patrol feature which can be used like so:

- GameObject A: (Cube, Cube Collider, Trigger = true, Disabled Mesh, Tag=PatrolPoint)
- GameObject B: (Cube, Cube Collider, Trigger = true, Disabled Mesh, Tag=PatrolPoint)
- GameObject C: npc that moves.

You would then need to create a script called "Patrol" that will handle the generation and ID of a patrol point. This script will be attatched to both GameObject A, and B.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Patrol : MonoBehavior 
{
    public int patrolID;

    public GameObject FindNextPoint() 
    {
        GameObject base;
        foreach(GameObject go in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PatrolPoint")) 
        {
            if(base == null && go.GetComponent<Patrol>().patrolID != patrolID) 
            {
                base = go;
            }
            if(go.GetComponent<Patrol>().patrolID == (patrolID) + 1) {
                return go;
            }
        }
        // Return the first object found in the scene that isn't this object.
        return base
    }

}
```

Next you would need to use the OnTriggerEnter() function of unity in your script that's attatched to the player (or npc moving)-- http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NpcScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private Vector3 targetLocation;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "PatrolPoint")
        {
            setWalkTo(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void setWalkTo(GameObject go) 
    {
        targetLocation = go.GetComponent<Patrol>().FindNextPoint().transform.position;
    }

}
```

You can have as many PatrolPoints as you want, just make sure to set the PatrolID variable to something different on each of them, the character will walk to them in order.

--- You have to add your own movement code, if you need help with that, let me know. Just move the gameobjects position towards targetLocation